What to do in Fall and Winter in Harvest Moon?
My daughter is playing Harvest Moon (SNES version) and we're confused as to what she is supposed to do in Fall and Winter. It's her first year (I think) and she has 12 squares of grass. According to the guides I've seen, you need 16 for livestock, so she can't get any of those yet. According to the guides, you also can't plant more grass (or any crops) in Fall or Winter. So, given her situation, is there anything she can do, other than just click through the days and wait for Spring? Perhaps she made a mistake with the planning and should have planted more grass in the first year, so she could start with the livestock?
Any tips would be appreciated!

Perhaps examine your guide more carefully to see if it actually has recommendations for Winter?
In any case, here's one guide's recommendations:

4.  W I N T E R   –   Y E A R   1                             HM34

Winter is the least active season in Harvest Moon.  Your days should be quite
free, as there is not even any fruit to gather from the mountain.  Winter is an
excellent time to continue building relationships and to get married.  Some of
the other goals this season are the following:

Continue to buy cows
Gather extra wood from the mountain
Upgrade your house for the second time
Continue to build relationships with the single women in town, especially Nina and Ann
Get married!



I didn't see any specific recommendations for what to do in Winter in the guides I looked at, but this is helpful - thanks!

@Time4Tea - Great! The guide I linked is a full game guide, so it also has Fall stuff if you're having trouble there too. Just that Winter's probably the time with the least amount of obvious stuff to do, IIRC.

Bear in mind, as I mentioned in the question, she only had 12 squares of grass going into her first Winter, so the game didn't allow her to buy any cows (further restricting the options). She ended up mostly just clicking through the days (which is obviously a bit tedious ...)

@Time4Tea - Yeah, there's really not a lot to do as there's literally nothing to take care of in that case. And betting that she's not just gonna reset. At least the game ends so she can try again later.
